# "Children could not be evaluated" when inspecting overridden ToString()

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to inspect values of `List<T>` when debugging, however I get "Children could not be evaluated" error if `T` overrides `ToString()`. I am using VS2017 and debugging Unity3D 5.6.0f project

example code:

```
void Start () {
   //if Sphere.ToString() is commented out, the contents are displayed correctly
   var obstacles = parser.ParseFile(Variables.Paths.DefaultScene).ToList();
}
//...
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]//with or without this attribute
public class Sphere
{
    public Vector3 Center { get; set; }
    public float Radius { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[r: " + Radius + " c: " + Center + "]";
    }
}
```

whether `T` is class or struct doesn't seem to any have effects, `DebuggerDisplay` attribute likewise has no effect - the list cannot be inspected regardless. The

```
var tmp = new Sphere();
```

however displays `tmp`'s `ToString()` correctly. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you found the solution to your problem? I am getting a similar problem with a class I derived from System.Dynamic.DynamicObject. DebuggerDisplay works as intended. but I get the error "Children could not be evaluated" expanding children of the instance in the watch view and it crashes the debugger (debugging stops). I am guessing it could be the same cause as yours. (I am not using Unity though so I think your problem has nothing to do with Unity either).

Comment: @sboisse no, sadly not. Debugging in Unity is still problematic (even though it seems less so with later versions). IEnumerable is no-go and other non-array collections work sporadically. Learnt living with it by printing to console when necessary. Pretty sure the problem is from Unity, more precisely the mono backend it is using - any other theories?

Comment: I have no Unity experience unfortunately. However I fixed my problem on my side as I realized I had an unintended recursive call in one of the overridden methods of my custom DynamicObject. So when VS2017 tried to display the content of my dynamic object in the watch panel, it was probably getting a stack overflow, causing the crash. After fixing the recursion everything worked as expected. So if your problem happens with just one of your own custom implementions and not the other ones, it probably has to do with something similar as my problem.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the documentation shows that you should either use a custom `ToString()` or a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute. Not both. Especially if the DebuggerDisplay is just a `{ToString()}` call.

Here's the documentation paragraph that mentions this issue:

> If a class has an overridden ToString() method, the debugger uses the
>   overridden method instead of the default {}. Thus, if you
>   have overridden the ToString() method, the debugger uses the
>   overridden method instead of the default{}, and you do not
>   have to use DebuggerDisplay. If you use both, the DebuggerDisplay
>   attribute takes precedence over the overridden ToString() method.

Source: [Using the DebuggerDisplay Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)

Comment: As mentioned in the question, presence or absence of `DebuggerDisplay` has no effect what so ever. The "Children could not be evaluated"  is always produced when attempting to inspect the list.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ToString() and just adding this on the header?
`[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("[r: {Radius} c: {Center}]")]`